# When are convex polygon tilings Voronoi?

Tags: geometry, tiling

A square is divided into convex polygons.  Is this always a [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)? If not, what are some simple examples of non-Voronoi tilings?

Which of the [pentagon tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling) are Voronoi?

I took a look at *Recognizing Dirichlet tessellations*. There are three rules right off:

1. At a Voronoi vertex, all angles $a < \pi$.
2. Let segment $p q$ be between two trivalent vertices, and let angles $p$ and $q$ be those angles that don't include $p q$. Then $p+q> \pi$.
3. If a Voronoi tessellation has more than one vertex, the generating points are uniquely determined.

There are other rules listed, but those three are a powerful start.

Comment: See [Recognizing Dirichlet tessellations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00181470).

Comment: Simple counterexample: draw a regular polygon with a quill directly outwards from each vertex: that is a voronoi diagram.  Now tilt all the quills slightly in one direction, say counterclockwise:  no longer a voronoi diagram.